# Find the curve of $ y = (Ax + B)^2$ for points $(k,2k^2+k)$,given$ (k=1,2...10)$

Tags: numerical-methods

I would like to solve this and run the matlab code:

since

$y=(Ax+B)^2=A^2x^2+2BAx+B^2$

let $A^2=\alpha  ,2AB=\beta,B^2=\gamma$

$\min{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma-f_m)^2}=\phi(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$

hence

I can get the values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ then  $A,B,C$

How can i write the matlab code for this?

Comment: You have an issue here. Your model has two parameters, but by expanding you're creating a third. In other words, if you solve your problem for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, you have no assurances that $\beta = 2\alpha\gamma$.

Comment: Oopps,now i see the folly,it was very tempting to directly expand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's re-write the problem as $$\log y = \log (Ax+B)^2 = 2 \log Ax + B.$$

Then,

$$Ax + B = \exp \frac{\log y}{2}.$$

Set up a Vandermonde matrix system:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 \\
1 & x_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n \end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{A}} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} B \\ A \end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{x}} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
\exp \frac{\log y_1}{2} \\
\exp \frac{\log y_2}{2} \\
\vdots \\
\exp \frac{\log y_n}{2}\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{b}}.$$

Solve the least squares problem as $$\mathbf{x} = \left(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{b}.$$

I'll provide you the MATLAB code if you give me assurances that this isn't a homework assignment.

---

Le codes:

```
x = (1:10)'; y = 2*x.^2+x;
A = [x.^0 x]; b = exp(log(y)/2);
z = (A'*A)\(A'*b);

plot(x, y,'.','MarkerSize',10)
hold on
plot(x, (z(2)*x+z(1)).^2,'ro')

sprintf('Coefficient A is %d,\nCoefficient B is %d',z(2),z(1))
```

Comment: powerful method.Its not homework,remember its holidays!!! Just been giving me worrying me for days now

Comment: In such a case, enjoy the codes.

Comment: succinct,clean method.Why is it illegal to just expand the expression?

Comment: @Jonas12 See my comment under your question.

Comment: $Gratias \space tibi \space ago$,have a great holiday :)

Comment: Why logs instead of a square root ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No particular reason other than log-transformations tend to be more common in practice.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as you think: if you plug a full parabolic model with three parameters, it will fit the data exactly and return $\alpha=2,\beta=1,\gamma=0$. (By the way, your parameter $C$ comes out of nowhere.)

Instead, you should minimize $\left((Ax+B)^2-y\right)^2$, which is a nonlinear problem.

Alternatively, you can linearize the model and fit $Ax+B=\sqrt y=z$.

The solution is known to be

$$A=\frac{\sum(z-\overline{z})(x-\overline x)}{\sum(x-\overline x)^2},\\
B=\overline z-A\overline x.$$

In your case,$$y\approx(1.4169\ x + 0.3272)^2$$

Comment: By the way, in the whole domain $y\approx(\sqrt2x+1/\sqrt8)^2=(1.4142\ x+0.3536)^2$ with a constant error of $1/8$.

Comment: That is a great argument ,so the reason why we can just make it quadratic is because $A,B$ are variables when we minimise.

Comment: It's because the quadratic model has three degrees of freedom, that enable an exact fit. Your $(A,B)$ model just has two and an exact fit is not possible.